# Deployment and dispersion in triangular regions

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, oc.optimization-and-control, computational-geometry

**Definitions** (from C. Stanley Ogilvy's '*Tomorrow's Math*'):

**Deployment:** To place a specified number $n$ of points (stations) in a region such that the maximum distance of any point in the region from one of the stations is minimized.

**Dispersal:** To place $n$ station points in a region such that the minimum distance among the stations is maximized.

**Question:** Are algorithms known for optimal (1) dispersal and (2) deployment of n stations on a triangular (polygonal) region?

*Remarks on Dispersal within triangles:* For $n =2$, it is best to place the stations at the ends of the longest side. For any higher $n$, it appears that $2$ of the stations should be kept at the ends of the longest side. For $n =3$, the third station is either (a) the third vertex of the triangle or (b) the point where the perpendicular bisector of the longest side cuts the rest of the triangle.

*Remarks on Deployment within triangles:* For n = 1, if the circumcenter of the triangle is in its interior, the lone station should be at the circumcenter. For deploying 2 points on a triangular region, the two stations seem to lie on the medial axis of the triangle. For larger $n$, I don't know. I also don't know if there are any special properties to the Voronoi regions that can result when n stations are optimally deployed in a convex region.

Comment: The two problems are known as the maximin and minmax Facility Location problems. Most variations are NP-hard.

Comment: I think the deployment problem for equilateral triangles is already nontrivial. Isn't it the same as asking for smallest circles you can use to cover a given triangle? If so, https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/circovtri/ gives answers for $1\le n\le9$.

Comment: Thanks Prof. O'Rourke for pointing out the more standard words for deployment and dispersion. Thanks Prof. Myerson for showing the connection between deployment and covering with disks - of course, Friedman discusses covering with equal disks and the deployment problem only needs the shortest distance to nearest station be minimized but it is intuitively clear that even if we allow the region to be covered with with disks of variable sizes and only insist that the biggest disk be minimized, we cannot get a smaller largest disk than in the case where all disks have to be equal.